# Topological sort using STL

Tags: c++, sorting, graph

I am trying to implement topological sort using STL. I have used vector of lists to store adjacency list. Indegree is an array which stores indegree of vertices.

`Indegree0` is a queue implemented using STL list to store vertices with indegree 0. Can someone please help me improve my code?

```
# include <iostream>  
# include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int> topologicalsort(vector<list<int> > adjacencylist,int  indegree[],int v,int e) 
{

    vector<int>ans(v+1);
    int k=1;
    //list to store vertices with indegree 0
    list<int>indegree0;
    for(int i=1;i<=v;i++)
    {
        if(indegree[i]==0)
            indegree0.push_back(i);
    }
    while(!indegree0.empty())
    {
        int x=indegree0.front();
        indegree0.pop_front();
        ans[k]=x;
        k++;
        list<int>::iterator itr=adjacencylist[x].begin();
        while(itr!=adjacencylist[x].end())
        {
            indegree[*itr]--;
            if(indegree[*itr]==0)
                indegree0.push_back(*itr);
            itr++;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    int v,e;
    cin>>v>>e;
    vector<list<int> > adjacencylist(v+1);
    int indegree[v+1];
    for(int i=1;i<=v;i++)
        indegree[i]=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=e;i++)
    {
        int v1,v2;
        cin>>v1>>v2;
        adjacencylist[v1].push_back(v2);
        indegree[v2]++;
    }
    //cout<<adjacencylist.size()<<endl;
    for(int i=1;i<=v;i++)
    {
        printf("adjacencylist[%d] :",i);
        list<int>::iterator itr=adjacencylist[i].begin();
        while(itr!=adjacencylist[i].end())
        {
            cout<<*itr<<"  ";
            itr++;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    vector<int> ans=topologicalsort(adjacencylist,indegree,v,e);
    for(int i=1;i<=v;i++)
        cout<<ans[i]<<"  ";

}
```

Comment: Seems to require an input stream on stdin - can you provide a sample input?

Answer (score 6):

## Headers and namespaces

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"
```

That's not a standard C++ header; prefer to use standard headers so that others can use your code.

```
using namespace std;
```

Bringing all names in from a namespace is problematic; `namespace std` particularly so. See [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1452721).

Used but not included: `<cstdio>`, `<vector>`,  `<list>`.  I'd recommend you stick to one of `<cstdio>` and `<iostream>`.

## Function signature

```
std::vector<int> topologicalsort(std::vector<std::list<int> > adjacencylist,
                                 int indegree[], int v,
                                 int e)
```

Why do you require `e`?  It's never used.

Passing `indegree` as a pointer and length is very C-style; prefer a C++ range (e.g. a pair of iterators, or a standard container).

There's no need to pass `adjacencylist` by value: a const-ref is more appropriate.

## Result vector

Instead of creating `v+1` elements in the result vector and having to keep track of our insert position with `k`, we can create it empty and `push_back` each result as we find it.  We can avoid reallocation by using `reserve()`.

## Looping over elements

Instead of the error prone iterator-based loop, prefer to use range-based `for` when applicable:

```
    for (int i: adjacencylist[x]) {
        if (--indegree[i] == 0)
            indegree0.push_back(i);
    }
```

## Variable-length arrays

This is a non-standard extension:

```
int indegree[v+1];
```

It's not clear why you ignore the 0th element of these arrays; that probably warrants a comment.

---

## Cleaned code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> topologicalsort(const std::vector<std::list<int>>& adjacencylist,
                                 std::vector<int> indegree)
{
    std::vector<int> ans;
    ans.reserve(indegree.size()+1);
    //list to store vertices with indegree 0
    std::list<int> indegree0;
    for (size_t i = 1;  i < indegree.size();  i++) {
        if (indegree[i] == 0)
            indegree0.push_back(i);
    }
    while (!indegree0.empty()) {
        const int x = indegree0.front();
        indegree0.pop_front();
        ans.push_back(x);
        for (const int i: adjacencylist[x]) {
            if (--indegree[i] == 0)
                indegree0.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    int v, e;
    std::cin >> v >> e;
    std::vector<std::list<int>> adjacencylist(v+1);
    std::vector<int> indegree(v+1);
    for (int i = 1;  i <= e;  i++) {
        int v1, v2;
        std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
        adjacencylist[v1].push_back(v2);
        ++indegree[v2];
    }
    for (int i = 1;  i <= v;  i++) {
        std::cout << "adjacencylist[" << i << "%d] :";
        for (int j: adjacencylist[i]) {
            std::cout << j << "  ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    auto const& ans = topologicalsort(adjacencylist, std::move(indegree));
    for (int i: ans)
        std::cout << i << "  ";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answer:

1. To make your intent clearer, use `std::queue` when you need queue. Don't reinvent the wheel. Don't confuse those who read your code.
2. Iteration over `std::list` is very inefficient because it lacks memory locality. Don't use it unless you have a very good reason to. Use `std::vector` as a default container.
3. Separate the words in variable's names somehow (either using camelCase or underscores). `topologicalsort` looks sort of gibberish. `topological_sort` or `topologicalSort` looks better, doesn't it?
4. Even if the input and output should have 1-based indexing, I'd still use 0-based indexing in computations. It's more conventional so it makes your code easier to understand (That's the main reason. Saving one element isn't a big deal).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers:

Why does the function `topological_sort` take more than one parameter? It should be able to calculate `indegree0` by itself.

Why is it restricted to `int` instead of allowing any type?

Comment: Not any type. Vertex ids are used as indices now, so they should be int-like.